# How to get a list of particular child object from Account

Tags: apex

I am new to Salesforce. My Account have 'Keys'(custom object) as child object. So in the Account page I could see list of Keys (name, value). Now I need to get the list of 'Keys' for the particular Account and then do some manipulation. I tried to write some apex code but couldn't find a way to

1. locate the  current account object
2. Get the list of all 'Keys' associated with that Account object

Any help is much appreciated. - Thank you.

Comment: This is possible with SOQL relationship queris https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using Share your code so that people can help you on that

Comment: [Building a Controller Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) and similar illustrate a common way to handle your first point.

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far? You could write a simple query to pick up the data such as `List<Key__c> keysForAccount = [Select Id, Name, Value__c, Account__c From Key__c Where Account__c = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']` but replacing the x's with your account Id, this will give you the related keys for the specified account, it might be a good start point to help you. Once you have built this out and worked on the code to manipulate the keys you can switch the Account Id to be a variable rather than a static Id and tie this into your process. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing related object fields is possible in both child to parent and parent to child ways. To address your problem, you can access the child `Keys` like in below Apex snippet.

```
// place a valid account id at the "accntId"
List<Account> accntsWithKeys = [SELECT Id, Name, 
                            (SELECT Id, Name, Custom_Field1__c FROM Keys__r)
                        FROM Account WHERE Id = 'accntId'];

for(Account a : accntsWithKeys){
    System.debug('account : ' + a.Name);
    // to access child objects iterate through children list
    for(Key__c k : a.Keys__r){
        System.debug('key : ' + k.Name);
    }
}
```

Note : In the given code snippet it's assumed that the API Name for child object is `Keys__r`. If the name differ, you can refer to the WSDL and get the correct API name for that.

To get an idea read on [Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using)

Answer (score 0):

To add to highfive's answer, if you do not need the `Account` fields in your processing (or just use the standard controller to access them), you can query the `Key__c` objects on their own:

```
public with sharing class AccountKeysExtension {
    public AccountKeysExtension(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        for (Key__c k : [
                select ...
                from Key__c
                where Account__c = :sc.getId()
                order by ...
                ) {
            // Key processing logic
        }
    }
}

<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountKeysExtension">
    ...
</apex:page>
```